# Get all fields except one

Tags: python, django

I am currently displaying my fields in the django admin interface via `model._meta.get_all_field_names()`. Now this works fine, but it also displays the Primary key  of the dataset (which doesn't look very nice in my opinion).

So my question is: Is there a "lazy" way to get all fields except for one/multiple? Or do I have to write every single field except for the one(s) I don't want to have displayed into a `list_display = array_of_fields_to_be_displayed`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `model._meta.fields` attribute which is a list of `Field` instances:

```
[field.name for field in model._meta.fields if not field.primary_key]
```

every `Field` has `primary_key` attribute (`True` if the field is the primary key) and `name` attribute (well, name of the field).

Working example on `auth.models.User`:

```
>>> [field.name for field in User._meta.fields if not field.primary_key]
['password', 'last_login', 'is_superuser', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'date_joined']
```

There is no `id` field in the output. Probably a good thing.